# linux server file download connection limit

Tags: php, nginx, centos, centos6

I'm running a dedicated server...
Centos 6
PHP 5.3.3
Nginx 1.0.15

Nginx uses fastcgi to run php.

The server communicates with another server using remote sql.

A file called download.php initiates a mysql connection, checks some details in the database and then begins streaming bytes to the user with content-displacement.

No matter what I do, I cannot get simultaneous connections to download a file above 5. For instance if I download a file using a file manager, a maximum of 5 connections can be made, the rest timeout.

I've setup nginx to accept up to 32 connections, mysql connection is closed before the file begins to stream so there shouldn't be connection limit issues there.

Does anybody have any idea how I can increase the amount of connections?
Perhaps an idea of what else I can check?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be the server cpu is overtaxed. Try running top to see the utilization during the downloads.

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. Nginx seems to be giving a return code 499 on the 6th request. Also it's max 5 connections every time, and when I want to download a second file it won't start because there seems to be a maximum of 5 connections for my ip.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/init.d/php_cgi
set server_childs=32

Problem solved!

Comment: What lead you to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the server is set to restrict by ip address. See http://www.nakedmcse.com/Home/tabid/39/forumid/14/postid/61/scope/posts/Default.aspx for more info.